# i have changed "email" column to "userEmail". now password reset in not working- laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.4, reset-password

i am using laravel auth. i changed the email column. and i am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` is
>   null)

i have changed all the email fields to userEmail in  ResetsPasswords and SendsPasswordResetEmails files and in views. i am new at laravel so i'm not understanding how it really works.

here is my password_resets table

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('userEmail', 50)->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('password_resets');
    }
}
```